# How to install base16 for iTerm2?

Tags: colorscheme, iterm2

I'm new to iTerm and vim and have been trying to follow readme at: https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell to try to get a theme to work in iTerm2/vim. The theme will only run if I chmod it and run it first then go to vim from there. On startup, iTerm will revert to the default theme in profiles. I have in `~/.config/base16-shell/`

```
base16-shell.png
colortest
profile_helper.sh
scripts
setting-256-colourspace-not-supported.png
templates
```

When I run colortest it doesn't pass the test specified at the bottom of the page https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell. However, from there I go in `/scripts` and run `base16-ocean.sh`, the theme is run, and from there if I run colortest again it passes.

I have in my vimrc:

```
let base16colorspace=256
colorscheme base16-ocean
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to run the script when your shell starts and it has to be ran from the `base16-vim` color scheme, [which is tersely documented](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell#shells) in `base16-shell`.  But, you don't want to use that script.  It'll just create more confusion later.

The "base 16" colors are the 8 standard colors + 8 brighter variants of those colors.  `base16`'s themes treat them as 16 *distinct* colors instead.  All shell programs that use color expect these colors to be what's labeled below, but have no idea what the *actual* color is on your screen.

[image: colors]

Using `base16` is fine if you're using a profile dedicated to Vim.  Otherwise, you will get non-obvious results if you use other programs that have no awareness of this.  For instance, if a program only uses the basic 8 colors and wants to display "bright green", it'll show up on your screen as a very dark gray, which won't be visible if you have a black background.

If your terminal supports palette customization (it does), the `base16-shell` script allows you to keep the standard 8 colors + 8 bright variants, but at the cost of changing five of the the [216 color palette](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Xterm_256color_chart.svg).  In the `base16` Vim colorscheme, it will use colors `0-7` and `17-21`, instead of `0-15`.

Colors `17-21` are shades of blue, which is shown in the troubleshooting section of the [README](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell#troubleshooting):

[image: blues]

Colors `16-231` are a fixed set of colors and programs that use this palette expect these colors to be constant.  So, you'll also get unexpected results if `17-21` are used by anything other than Vim, which again, is fine if you are fully aware of this and use a separate profile just for Vim.

This was a clever approach, but IMO, gives little guidance to users and is far too much effort to alter a well established palette to get a pretty color scheme.  For a little bit less effort, you can get the latest build of Vim (v7.4.1799+) or Neovim (v0.1.5 [dev]) and use the `termguicolors` setting to use the `#rrggbb` GUI colors instead since iTerm2 supports truecolor.  Then you wouldn't be limited to 256 colors and can use *any* of the `base16-vim` color schemes without screwing up the shell's colors.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I have to run base16-shell every time I open the terminal to have the colors available in vim? If not, what would be the steps to do so?